# Which Fragment opened the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment, android-optionsmenu

I have a viewpager,it has 4 fragments and all of them have recyclerview. On click of recyclerview,all four of the fragments open the same activity i.e. DemoActivity. I want to show different options menu in DemoActivity according to which fragmnet's recyclerview was clicked. How come i would know which fragment's recyclerview was clicked and show appropriate Oprtions Menu in DemoActivity?

```
  public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public CategoryAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            return new MyMoviesFragment();
        }
        else if(position==1){
            return new PopularFragment();
        }
        else if (position==2){
            return new UpComingFragment();
        }
        else{
            return new NowPlayingFragment();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            return context.getString(R.string.category_MyMovies);
        }
        else if(position==1){
            return context.getString(R.string.category_Popular);
        }

        else if(position==2){
            return context.getString(R.string.category_Upcoming);
        }
        else if(position==3){
            return context.getString(R.string.category_NowPlaying);
        }

        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
}
```

Question has been edited

Comment: u can pass value through intent.
can u please share the code ?

Comment: the code is very long

Comment: Not sure if this will work with Fragments but try `referrer.getHost()`

Comment: @MehmetKologlu what's referrer.How to create object of it?

Comment: Correction: `ActivityCompat.getReferrer(this).getHost()` where this is your Activity. Or perhaps you can just use the referrer, not the host, dont really know.

Answer (score 0):

```
in fragment (u can put this code inside your recycler view action listener )
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DemoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "UR_FRAGMENT_NAME");
startActivity(intent);

in DemoActivity inside onCreate() method
Intent intent  = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("KEY")) {
   if(intent.getStringExtra("KEY").equals("UR_FRAGMENT_NAME")) {
     // todo what u want.
   }
}
```

Comment: but the click event is handled in Adaapter class and all the four fragments have the same Adapter class

Comment: just pass the instance on current fragment inside ur adapter while create constructor.
UrAdapter adapter = new UrAdapter(Fragment fragment);

Comment: But in my Adapter's Constructor,i am passing Context which is of the activity and all fragments share the MainActivity

Comment: UrAdapter adapter = new UrAdapter(Fragment fragment);
inside ur adapter where u are using context replace it to
context replace it fragment.getActivity()

inside adapter action check
if(fragment instanceof UR_FRAGMENT_ONE) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DemoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "UR_FRAGMENT_NAME");
startActivity(intent);
} else if(fragment instanceof UR_FRAGMENT_TWO) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DemoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "UR_FRAGMENT_NAME");
startActivity(intent);
}

Answer (score 0):

If you got a `ViewPager` - there is an option of position that you can utilize. Pass the position of your `fragment` and put the condition of positions into your `DemoActivity.java`.

To do so, you have to pass position from your `FragmentPagerAdpater`'s `getItem(int position)` method, and pass the position from `Fragment` to an `Activity`.

Just like -

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment mF;
    if (position == 0) {
       mF = new MyMoviesFragment();
    } else if (position==1){
       mF = new PopularFragment();
    } else if (position==2){
       mF = new UpComingFragment();
    } else {
       mF = new NowPlayingFragment();
    }
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("KEY", position); // You are passing position to fragment
    mF.setArguments(b);
    return mF;
}
```

Now get position in your `fragment` using `getArguments()` method. For an example, in your `MyMoviesFragment` -

```
Bundle b = getArguements();
int position = b.getInt("KEY");
```

You've got your position in `Fragment`, now pass it to the `Activity` inside the click of `recyclerview` item -

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, DemoActivity.class);
i.putExtra("NEW_KEY", position); // position is being passed to activity, retrieve in Activity using getExtras() and use it as needed.
startActivity(i);
```

You're done!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to put condition of positions into your DemoActivity.java.

Comment: Alright, first tell me - do you have position in `Fragment`? If yes, are you able to get and event of `recycleview` item click?

Comment: yes i have position in Fragment but how to retrieve it.public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public CategoryAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            return new MyMoviesFragment();
        }
        else if(position==1){
    return new PopularFragment()}else if (position==2){return new UpComingFragment(); }else{return new NowPlayingFragment();}}
   .............}

Comment: Post you code in with an edit in your question rather than posting in a comment. This is unreadable.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Added some snippets, have a look.